# CSS grid broken when I replace the background image with an image tag

Tags: css

I have a small problem to fix.
I create a CSS grid.
This is the grid.

```css
  .cover {
    max-width: 1080px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
  }

figure {
    margin: 1px;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }

.horizontal {
    padding-top: calc(700 / 1400 * 100%);
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 1;
    max-width: 720px;
  }
  .large {
    padding-top: calc(700 / 700 * 100%);
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 2;
    max-width: 720px;
  }
  .vertical {
    padding-top: calc(560 / 360 * 100%);
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 2;
    max-width: 360px;
  }
  .small {
    padding-top: calc(700 / 700 * 100%);
    grid-column: span 1;
    grid-row: span 1;
    max-width: 360px;
  }
```

```html
<section class="cover">
  <figure style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('https://via.placeholder.com/1350x700.png?text=1350x700')" class="horizontal"></figure>
  <figure style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('https://via.placeholder.com/675x700.png?text=675x700')" class="small"></figure>
    <figure style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('https://via.placeholder.com/675x700.png?text=675x700')" class="small"></figure>
      <figure style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('https://via.placeholder.com/675x700.png?text=675x700')" class="small"></figure>
        <figure style="background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('https://via.placeholder.com/675x700.png?text=675x700')" class="small"></figure>
</section>
```

I need to remove the image from the `figure tag` background style, replacing it with an image tag.
At the same time the image must be clickable.

I try with

```
<section class="cover">
  <a href="">
    <figure class="horizontal">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1350x700.png?text=1350x700">
    </figure>
 </a>
 <a href="">
 <figure class="small">
       <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/700x700.png?text=1350x700">
    </figure>
 <a href="">
 ....
```

but I cannot find a way to keep the grid. Everything is broken.

Edit: I add two information.
The grid is generated dynamically by the backend and has different layouts, the structure of every tile must be the same.

The size and the aspect ratio of every tile is defined by the class that of course is assigned to the element according to the layout.

So I have to use a class.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your style like this.

```
...

  a {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 1;
    max-width: 720px;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 720px;
  }

  .horizontal {
    grid-column: span 2;
    grid-row: span 1;
    max-width: 720px;
  }

...
```